# How to select a file from a Drop-down list which gives a list of files in a folder and later upload the selected file

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, file-upload

I am trying to make an Upload function using drop-down list. The basic idea is the drop-down box lists all the files from a folder and when a user selects a file from the drop-down list, it should be uploaded.

My HTML-Form:

```
> <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
>      <label for="fileToUpload"><b> Select file to Upload:</b></label>
>       <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
>       <select name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
>       <?php
>         $directory = "/some/folder/in/server";                                          //location of directory with files
>         $scanned_directory = array_diff(scandir($directory), array("..", "."));         //removes . and .. files whic$
>         $files = array_map("htmlspecialchars", $scanned_directory);                     //scans directory and returns$
>           foreach ($files as $file) {
>             echo "<option value='$file'>$file</option>";
>           }
>       ?>
>       </select>
>       <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit">
>      </form>
```

upload.php

```
<?php

$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$success = "File " . basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " uploaded.";
$fail = "Error uploading file.";

  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    //echo "The file " . basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$success');</script>";
    echo "<script>window.location='index.php'</script>";
  } else {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$fail');</script>";
    echo "<script>window.location='index.php'</script>";
  }

?>
```

The code works fine if i just use  but doesn't work with the drop-down list. I although can list out the files in a folder but am having problem regarding selecting the file and uploading it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're displaying a list of files from some location on the server, then expecting the user to upload one of those files from their workstation? Even without the security implications, I can't see how that would ever work.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular So it's also not Possible to restrict file upload from a particular folder? The thing is I want my Webpage to be tested by someone else and so that he/she doesn't get access to sensitive information on our server, I want to restrict file upload to a particular folder

Answer (score 1):

You are just looking for a dirty way to copy files...
Here is how to do it
First remove `enctype="multipart/form-data` and `<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">` from your **HTML** form

Then your **PHP**

```
<?php
$name = $_POST["fileToUpload"];
$scanned_dir = "/some/folder/in/server/".$name; //The previous location of the file
$target_dir = "uploads/".$name; //The destination

if(!copy($scanned_dir,$target_dir)){ //Check if the transfer is successful
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('fail');</script>";
      echo "<script>window.location='index.php'</script>";
}
else{ 
    //echo "The file ".$name." has been uploaded.";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('success');</script>";
    echo "<script>window.location='index.php'</script>";
}
?>
```

If you want to move the file instead...
use rename() instead of copy()

Answer (score 0):

You can only use an `<input type="file" />` to upload files for security reasons. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1553777/1772933